# Using jQuery dataTables in a Symfony2 | Doctrine | Twig project - mixing some features to have select tag filters displaying results in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatable, twig

I am working on a **Symfony** project, with **Twig** template and **Doctrine**, using `jQuery DataTables` for manage my doctrine'datas in some twig pages.

In my database, I have the relationship between some datatables like this example:

```
    adverts
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | int(11)      |
| ...         | ...          |
+-------------+--------------+

    adverts_categories 
+---------------+--------------+
| adverts_id    | int(11)      |
| categories_id | int(11)      |
+---------------+--------------+

    categories
+-------------+-------------+
| id          | int(11)     |
| ...         | ...         |
+-------------+-------------+
```

This is my **controller**:

```
public function indexAdvertsAction() {

       $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $advert= $em->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Adverts')->findAll();

       return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:indexAdverts.html.twig', array('advert' => $advert ));
}
```

Then in a **twig**, I display the results in a `<table>` like this:

```
<table id="dataTableAdvert">
     <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Users</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Categories</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Comment(s)</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Users</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Categories</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Comment(s)</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
     </tfoot>
     <tbody>
       {% for adverts in advert%}
         <tr>
           <td>{{ adverts.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ adverts.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ adverts.users }}</td>
           <td>
             {% for category in adverts.categories %}
                 {{ adverts.categories }}
             {% endfor %}
           </td>
         </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So everyting for displaying the results are good, except the responsive.

And I would like to use the jQuery DataTables by mixing some various features.

Look at this picture:
[image]

This picture take some examples of jQuery dataTables possibilities. I already use ColVis extensions.
But in fact, I would like to add three others parameters:

- using [Custom filtering - range search](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)
  But as you can see on my image, I would like to have  `tags` instead of *input text*. And when I select a value (users for example) in this select, results will be display in my datatable. And in this case, I can remove the users and categories column.
- moreover, I would like to not display the column users when the pages is launched, like you can see, with ColVis, I can Hide or Show the column I want. I would like the users column is not visible at first, except if I choose in the ColVis the users checkbox for showing the user column.
- make my datatables really responsive, because for now my datatables is not collapsing in my panel body.

This for now my javascript code for my dataTables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#dataTableAdvert').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();
            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                //select tag search input under colum 1
                if (i == 1) {
                    var column = api.column( i );
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    });
                }
                //select tag search input under colum 2
                if (i == 2) {
                    var column = api.column( i );
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        responsive: true,
    });
});
```

Someone could help me to organize and make this features?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use a more sophisticated tool than DataTables.

I have had some good successes with [Simile Exhibit](http://simile-widgets.org/exhibit/) for user interfaces like this. You can try out the [Presidents example](http://simile-widgets.org/exhibit3/examples/senate/senate.html) for table selection tools if that meets user UI interactivity requirements. There are also range selection tools for numeric values if you need.

It take a while to learn, but its worth it in the long term.